# does Web Accessibillity works well with Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, accessibility, backbone-views, wai-aria

I am facing issues using Web Accessibility (using ARIA) with Backbone. When a view is getting rendered, automatically focus is going to that view and screen reader is reading that section in the order views are getting rendered. Is this the right behavior? I want to control this as I want screen reader to read the content the order I want. Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using templates for your views you can put your ARIA attributes in the HTML tag.

```
<ul role="tablist">
 <li id="ch1Tab" role="tab">
  {{data}}
 </li>
</ul>
```

as far as screen readers it reads it from top to bottom but it doesn't trigger it to read the page again.

here is a discussion on the approach [Accessibility and all these JavaScript frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370056/accessibility-and-all-these-javascript-frameworks)

Javascript is not an issue its the foundation of the markup that is rendered in the browser. w

Comment: Thank you Nol for the update, Here is the code I am re-rendering after change in combo box (combo box contains list of accounts). I want to refresh the view with out calling view. is this possible. Below function is called for each change in combo box acctRefresh: function(){
            this.render(); 
            acctHeadView.render();
            acctFooterView.render();
            /*$('#acctDetailSub').focus();
             $('#acctDetail').focus();
             $('#headChange').focus();*/
            $('#modelName').val(selVal);

        }

Comment: My question was is there a way to update the view with out calling render function again as this is causing the problem. Looking similar to Angular binding. Thank you.

Comment: if you have an event .. like a click you can do something like this `$('.target').append(this.$el.html(this.template()))` but you need someway to trigger it